# Rails Combining and Sorting ActiveRecord Relations when using polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on a small collection tracker where I feel like STI could really simplify this problem but it seems the general consensus is to avoid STI whenever possible so I have broken my models apart.  Currently, they are all the same but I do have a few different bits of metadata that I can see myself attaching to them.

Anyways, the root is a `Platform` which has many `Games`, `Systems`, `Peripherals`, etc. and I am trying to show all of these relations on a view in a dynamic table that is filterable, sortable and searchable.

For example a query could be `@platform.collectables.search(q).order(:name)`.

```
# Schema: platforms[ id, name ]
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
  has_many :systems
  has_many :peripherals
end

# Schema: games[ id, platform_id, name ]
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform
end

# Schema: systems[ id, platform_id, name ]
class System < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform
end

# Schema: peripherals[ id, platform_id, name ]
class Peripheral < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform
end
```

In the above, the polymorphism comes into play when I add them to a `Collection`:

```
# Schema: collections[ id, user_id, collectable_type, collectable_id ]
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :collectable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now, when I view a `Platform`, I expect to see all of its games, systems and peripherals which I refer to as collectables.  How would I query all of these while being able to sort as a whole (ie: "name ASC").  Below works in theory but this changes the relation to an Array which stops me from further filtering, searching or reordering at the database level so I can't tag on another `scope` or `order`.

```
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
...

  def collectables
    games + systems + peripherals
  end
end
```

I stumbled on [Delegated Types](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39341) which kind of sounds like the step in the direction that I am looking for but maybe I am missing something.

I'm tempted to try the STI route, I don't see these models diverging much and things that are different could be stored inside of a JSONB column cause it's mostly just metadata for populating a view with and not really searching against.  Basically a model such as this but it seems so frowned upon, I feel like I must be missing something.

```
# Schema: collectables[ id, platform_id, type, name, data ]
class Collectable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform
end

class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collectables

  def games
    collectables.where(type: 'Game')
  end

  def systems
    collectables.where(type: 'System')
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to overcome? How does polymorphism solve this? Why is a "Collection" necessary when it appears to simply be the sum of its parts?  Personally I feel like STI or polymorphism might just convolute the situation but maybe I don't understand the problem clearly enoguh. If those models share certain attributes (by naming convention only) that is fine. If they share presentation or methodolgy you can simplify this logic through composition Modules.

Comment: @engineersmnky The polymorphism comes into play when I need to relate the collectables to a user, so I don't think it's part of the problem because I can properly filter a users collection to them in a view by the polymorphic column.  The problem I am having is when I want to show all collectables in relation to a platform while still being able to filter, search or sort (dynamic table).  Combining the 3 objects turns them to an array which stops me from performing searches effectively on the database level.  So in effect... `@platform.collectables.search(q).order("name desc")`

Comment: STI is suitable for the data which share most of their table columns. If you think it's exact your situation, there is no reason to stop you doing STI. I think there are people against STI is because that even some models seems very alike at the beginning, but they become more and more different as the time goes by. As a result you need to maintain a extremely big table.
I have an experimental solution that I extract the common fields and do STI, then use has_one relation for the specific fields for each STI child model. It's similar to your JSONB solution.

Comment: Another idea is to use UNION SQL phrase if you don't want to use STI

Comment: @kevinluo201 I think STI will work well, especially when coupled with a `data:jsonb` column on the table that can store metadata that is different between the real world objects, ie: Game.first.data['number_of_players'].

I understand that in the future things could expand which is why I wanted to look at the polymorphic route first but I've been hung up trying to combine the separated models while still being able to chain them with other scopes.  Maybe it cannot be done via plain ActiveRecord?

Comment: I don't think number_of_players is metadata for a game, it should be an attribute. I did't even know delegated types existed in Rails but they do seem to be a fit-for-purpose solution

Comment: "I don't see these models diverging much" - famous last words.

Comment: I don't know if you have thought of the potential fatal flaw in this solution - since you're putting the foreign key on the collectables table then it can only ever belong to a single collection. This creates the potential for a huge amount of denormalization as you would have to duplicate everything. Instead you most likely want a join a table (or several join tables if you reject the STI idea).

Comment: @max famous last words are exactly why I am favouring splitting into separate models :) anyways, `Collection` is my join table between `User` and the polymorphic `Collectable (Game, System, Peripheral)`.  Or are you in favour of the STI route?  I prototyped the STI route this afternoon and it does solve all my querying issues, just not the "future diverging" issues.  In my polymorphic test, I created one more join table `PlatformCollectable` to try the delegated types but am still struggling to sort by name on it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution here would be [Delegated Type](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) (a relatively new Rails feature) which can basically be summarized as Multiple Table Inheritance through polymorphism. So you have a base table containing the shared attributes but each class also has its own table - thus avoiding some of  the key problems of STI.

```
# app/models/concerns/collectable.rb
# This module defines shared behavior for the collectable "subtypes"
module Collectable
  TYPES = %w{ Game System Peripheral }
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :base_collectable, as: :collectable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :base_collectable
  end 
end
```

```
# This model contains the base attributes shared by all the collectable types
# rails g model base_collectable name collectable_type collectable_id:bigint
class BaseCollectable < ApplicationRecord 
  # this sets up a polymorhic association
  delegated_type :collectable, types: Collectable::TYPES
end
```

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  include Collectable
end
```

```
class Peripheral < ApplicationRecord
  include Collectable
end
```

```
class System < ApplicationRecord
  include Collectable
end
```

You can then setup a many to many assocation through a join model:

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :collection_items
  has_many :base_collectables, through: :collection_items

  has_many :games, 
    through: :base_collectables, 
    source_type: 'Game'
  has_many :peripherals, 
    through: :base_collectables, 
    source_type: 'Peripheral'
  has_many :systems, 
    through: :base_collectables, 
    source_type: 'Systems'
end
```

```
class CollectionItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :base_collectable
end
```

```
# This model contains the base attributes shared by all the collectable types
# rails g model base_collectable name collectable_type collectable_id:bigint
class BaseCollectable < ApplicationRecord 
  # this sets up a polymorhic association
  delegated_type :collectable, types: %w{ Game System Peripheral }
  has_many :collection_items
  has_many :collections, through: :collection_items
end
```

This lets you treat it as a homogenius collection and order by columns on the `base_collectables` table.

### The big but - the relational model still doesn't like cheaters

Polymorphic assocations are a dirty cheat around the object relational impedence missmatch by having one columns with a primary key reference and another storing the class name. Its not an actual foreign key since the assocation cannot resolved without first pulling the records out of the database.

This means you can't setup a `has_many :collectables, through: :base_collectables` association. And you can't eager load all the delegated types or order the entire collection by the columns on the games, peripherals or systems tables.

It does work for the specific types such as:

```
has_many :games, 
    through: :base_collectables, 
    source_type: 'Game'
```

Since the table can be known beforehand.

This is simply a tough nut to crack in relational databases which are table based and not object oriented and where relations in the form of foreign keys point to a single table.

### VS STI + JSON

The key problem here is that all the data you're stuffing into the JSON column is essentially schemaless and you're restricted by the 6 types supported by JSON (none of which is a date or decent number type) and working with the data can be extremely difficult.

JSON's main feature is it simplicity which worked well enough as a transmission format. As a data storage format its not really that great.

It's a huge step up from the EAV table or storing YAML/JSON serialized into a varchar column but its still has huge caveats.

### Other potential solutions

- STI. Fixes one the polymorphism problem and introduces a bunch more.
- A [materized view](https://pganalyze.com/blog/materialized-views-ruby-rails) that is populated with a union of the three tables can be treated as table and thus can simply have an ActiveRecord relation attached to it.
- Union query. Basically the same idea as above but you just use the raw query results or feed them into a model representing a non-sensical table.
- Non-relational database. Document based databases like MongoDB let you create flexible documents and non-homogenius collections by design while having better type support.

Comment: This is actually very similar to the route I am currently on, the new delegated types feels like the accurate solution for the problem.  I like some of your naming better than my current choices (BaseCollectable).  I'm no stranger to normal rails polymorphic behaviour so the new delegated types hasn't been too bad to.  

It solves my original problem of searching, filtering and ordering if I move my `name` attributes off the `Collectables` and put it onto the `BaseCollectable` instead.  Allowing me to `@platform.base_collectables.where(X).order(:name)`.

I think this is the right choice.